# Is it possible to split the output console in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to have *multiple* python consoles side to side or as independent windows in PyCharm?

Note: I am already using *Windowed Mode* to have the console panel as a window, but I want to have separate consoles on separate windows.

I am using PyCharm Professional 2018.1

I open a Python console via View -> Tool Windows -> Python console. Clicking on the green "plus" symbol I can open multiple consoles, but they are showed as different tabs.

[image]

What I would like it being able to see the "content" of multiple console at the same time, hence having them side to side or as independent windows I can arrange as I want.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [splitting console is still a feature in request right now for Pycharm 2018.2.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13095) as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845961/pycharm-view-runs-in-split-mode).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that this is the answer. I edited my question to make my objective more clear (I hope)

Comment: Updated my answer after quick Google search

Comment: Well done on your first answer. Please change your answer to only address the question asked please - thus removing the part before the edit. Also including key text from links is helpful as links can be removed over time. And instead of 'impossible' state which version this relates to as the situation may change in the future.

Comment: @tda Thanks for the suggestion